# i'm trying to make a dinamic checkbox in react using a state that combine multiple states but checkbox value is always "on" not even false or true

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i have tried already to assign the checkbox checked=true so the btn works.
i also tried to get to the value of the checkbox either from the e.target.value/checked but also no good came from it. if someone can help me i will be most greatful. thanks a lot
here is the code:

here is the checkbox element:

```
  <label key={uuidv4()}>
            <span>{masters[index].free_text}</span>
            <input
              type="checkBox"
              name={masters[index].name}
              id={masters[index].name}
              checked={false}
              required={masters[index].required}
              // value={inputsAdContent.name?"true":"false"}
              onChange={handleChangeAdContent}
            />
          </label>
```

when the element is looking like this i get false at  all times and it doesnt change

```
<label key={uuidv4()}>
            <span>{masters[index].free_text}</span>
            <input
              type="checkBox"
              name={masters[index].name}
              id={masters[index].name}
              
              required={masters[index].required}
              value={inputsAdContent.name==="true" ? "true" : "false"}
              onChange={handleChangeAdContent}
            />
          </label>
```

and here is the onChange:

```
 <label key={uuidv4()}>
            <span>{masters[index].free_text}</span>
            <input
              type="checkBox"
              name={masters[index].name}
              id={masters[index].name}
              
              required={masters[index].required}
              value={inputsAdContent.name==="true" ? "true" : "false"}
              onChange={handleChangeAdContent}
            />
          </label>
```

at the console i get this msg:

```
air_conditioner: "on"
```

this is the state i'm using:

```
const [inputsAdContent, setInputsAdContent] = useState({});
```

thank you all very much!!!

Comment: even when i take off the comment the output remains the same. i just commented it because i wanted to explore the checked property which  doesnt work as well

Comment: Ah, i see. I don't know exactly what you're after but it looks like `inputsAdContent.name` should be `inputsAdContent[masters[index].name]` to start with. Also `checked` expects a boolean, so if you're passing the strings from the value you'll need to convert them to booleans. Perhaps make a codesandbox with more context for further help.